# Check if variable returns true

Tags: php

I want to echo 'success' if the variable is true. (I originally wrote "returns true" which only applies to functions.

```
$add_visits = add_post_meta($id, 'piwik_visits', $nb_visits, true);
if($add_visits == true){
         echo 'success';
}
```

Is this the equivalent of

```
$add_visits = add_post_meta($id, 'piwik_visits', $nb_visits, true);
if($add_visits){
         echo 'success';
}
```

Or does $add_visits exist whether it is 'true' or 'false';

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Testing `$var == true` is the same than just testing `$var`.

You can read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis) on comparison operator.
You can also read [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) on this topic.

Note: a variable does not *return* `true`. It **is** `true`, or it **evaluates** to `true`. However, a function **returns** `true`.

Answer (score 22):

You might want to consider:

```
if($add_visits === TRUE){
     echo 'success';
}
```

This will check that your value is TRUE and of type boolean, this is more secure. As is, your code will echo success in the event that $add_visits were to come back as the string "fail" which could easily result from your DB failing out after the request is sent.

Comment: for laravelers:  there is a default function under \PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint namespace :  **isTrue($a_value)**

Answer (score 9):

They're the same.

This...

```
if ($add_visits == true)
    echo 'success';
```

...Is the same as:

```
if ($add_visits)
    echo 'success';
```

In the same fashion, you can also test if the condition is false like this:

```
if (!$add_visits)
    echo "it's false!";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($add_visits === TRUE)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The most secure way is using php validation. In case of a ajax post to php:

```
$isTrue=filter_var($_POST['isTrue'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that would work fine.

```
//true
if($variable) echo "success";
if($variable == true) echo "success";


//false
if(!$variable) echo "failure";
if($variable == false) echo "failure";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($add_visits) && $add_visits === TRUE){
     echo 'success';
}
```

Might seem redundant, but PHP will throw a `Notice` if `$add_visits` isn't set. This would be the safest way to test if a variable is true.

Answer (score 0):

Noncompliant Code Example

```
if ($booleanVariable == true) { /* ... */ }
if ($booleanVariable != true) { /* ... */ }
if ($booleanVariable || false) { /* ... */ }
```

doSomething(!false);

```
Compliant Solution
if ($booleanVariable) { /* ... */ }
if (!$booleanVariable) { /* ... */ }
if ($booleanVariable) { /* ... */ }
```

doSomething(true);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).